# ¿Cómo obtengo la suma de todos los bonos?

Tags: sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta en SQL Server:

```
select distinct bono_aux AS BONO, FECHA_ARQUEO from arqueo 
where RUT_AUX <>'0' and RUT_AUX='18460678-K'
and FECHA_ARQUEO between '2017-03-30' and '2017-04-13'
order by FECHA_ARQUEO asc
```

la cual me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: Bonos diarios para cada auxiliar, segun la fecha]

Hasta aquí todo bien. Ahora mi problema es cómo realizar la suma de todos los bonos diarios y devolverlo en un solo campo "SUMA_BONOS". He probado con SUM(DISTINCT "BONO_AUX") pero me dá errores.

Comment: puede haber más de un bono por fecha para un `RUT_AUX`?

Comment: solo un bono por dia

Answer (score 3):

Si es sólo un valor de bono por día para un `RUT_AUX`, entonces puedes escribir simplemente:

```
SELECT SUM(bono_aux) Total_Bono
FROM arqueo 
WHERE RUT_AUX='18460678-K' -- la condición RUT_AUX <>'0' no es necesaria en este caso
AND FECHA_ARQUEO BETWEEN '2017-03-30' AND '2017-04-13'
;
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Si hay más de un valor de bono por día por rut, y sólo quieres sumar los distintos, entonces debes hacer algo diferente:

```
SELECT SUM(bono_aux) Total_Bono
FROM (  SELECT DISTINCT bono_aux,
                        FECHA_ARQUEO
        FROM arqueo 
        WHERE RUT_AUX='18460678-K' -- la condición RUT_AUX <>'0' no es necesaria en este caso
        AND FECHA_ARQUEO BETWEEN '2017-03-30' AND '2017-04-13') t
;
```

Comment: Al ejecutar la consulta me arroja como Total_Bono "1280000" y debería retornar "160000" no sé por qué

Comment: La Consulta que estas Mostrando es la que te retorna los Datos .. puedes mostrarnos que te retorna solamente                                                                                            select bono_aux AS BONO, FECHA_ARQUEO from arqueo 
where  RUT_AUX='18460678-K'
and FECHA_ARQUEO between '2017-03-30' and '2017-04-13'
order by FECHA_ARQUEO asc
;     de preferencia copia y pega los datos para poder manipularlos ..

Comment: @FranciscoVargas pues probablemente porque no hay solamente un valor de bono por día por `RUT_AUX`

Comment: Retorna esto:
15000 2017-03-30 (8 veces esta misma linea)
15000 2017-03-31 (8 veces esta misma linea)
20000 2017-04-03 (8 veces esta misma linea)
15000 2017-04-04 (8 veces esta misma linea)
10000 2017-04-05 (8 veces esta misma linea)
10000 2017-04-06 (8 veces esta misma linea)
15000 2017-04-07(8 veces esta misma linea)
15000 2017-04-08(8 veces esta misma linea)
15000 2017-04-11(8 veces esta misma linea)
10000 2017-04-12(8 veces esta misma linea)
20000 2017-04-13(8 veces esta misma linea)
 
por eso usaba el distinct

Comment: @FranciscoVargas Pero por eso mismo hice la consulta si había un sólo valor de bono por día por rut....

Comment: es que al final es un solo valor el que necesito ya que se repite el mismo por 8 veces

Comment: Sí, pero mi pregunta era sobre los datos que tenías. De todas formas, actualicé mi respuesta

Comment: gracias amigaso :)